# Haskell handling getting Int from user input

Tags: haskell, io

In my program I need to make a decision based on user input. Let's say the valid inputs are `one`, `two`, `three`. I first need to convert such an input to an Int because I need to compare it to other data in my program. Which is why I have a function `toInt :: String -> Int` which turns a String into an Int (one = 1, two = 2, three = 3). As of now I try to use `getLine` to retrieve the user input however this is of type `IO String` so I can't use my function with this input.

Thus my questions are: should I use getLine in this case? And if so how can I modify the user input or `toInt` so that it will work? And if not what else can I do so that I can get `toInt` to work with the user input?

Comment: For one, `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)` could be specialized into `fmap :: (String -> Int) -> (IO String -> IO Int)`, so you'd have `fmap toInt :: IO String -> IO Int` - which would get you a way to obtain an IO action giving `Int`. You would better follow detailed explanation and exercise for IO, though.

Comment: Hello! This is a basic question on how input and output work in Haskell. Have you tried to read up any material explaining the topic? For example: https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_IO